# How to indicate someone stood in for someone else on meeting minutes?

Tags: phrase-request, formal-language

We have person A who normally takes notes. Person A was sick, now Person B did the notes. Would it make sense as follows in the meeting minutes?

> Secretary: Person A, but stand-in Person B

Comment: Minutes of meetings usually include a list of those present and those sending their apologies, so A would be among the latter and B's name could be followed by _(deputising for A)_ or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to the person as **Acting Secretary**. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/acting) has

> **acting**
> <sub>ADJECTIVE</sub>
>
> Temporarily doing the duties of another person.

So the minutes of the meeting might say

> Acting Secretary: Weather Vane